# What topological spaces satisfy a property involving relatively compact sets?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

A subset of a topological space is called relatively compact if its closure is compact.  My question is, what kind of topological spaces satisfy the following property: for every relatively compact set $S$, there exists a relatively compact set $T$ such that the closure of $S$ is a subset of the interior of $T$?

Is there some category of topological spaces which satisfies this property?  And is there an example of a $T_1$ space which does not satisfy this property?

My reason for asking this, by the way, is that relatively compact subsets of a $T_1$ form a [bornology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space), and this property says that that bornology interacts well with the topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is equivalent to [local compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space).

If a topological space satisfies your property, then a singleton point set $\{x\}$ is compact, and hence there must be a relatively compact set $T$ whose interior contains $x$ (in fact, it contains $\overline{\{x\}}$, which may be strictly larger). The closure of $T$ is a compact neighbourhood of $x$.

If, on the other hand, if we have locally compact space and a relatively compact set $S$, then $\overline{S}$ is compact. For each point $s \in \overline{S}$, there is an open neighbourhood $\mathcal{N}_s$ of $s$ that is compact. Note that the interiors of these neighbourhoods cover $\overline{S}$, hence there must be a finite-subcover of $\overline{S}$. Unioning this finite subcover yields an open, relatively compact neighbourhood containing $\overline{S}$, establishing equivalence.

Comment: I just posted a follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3048148/71829

Comment: And now I posted one more follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3048232/71829

Comment: @TheoBendit In the second paragraph the singleton $\{x\}$ is compact, but is not necessarily relatively compact.  (for example consider the particular point in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology)  So I don't think one can conclude the existence of a compact nbhd of $x$.