# What topological spaces satisfy another property involving relatively compact sets?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

This is a follow-up to my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3047093/71829). A subset of a topological space is called relatively compact if its closure is compact.  My question is, what kind of topological spaces satisfy the following property: there exist countably many relatively compact sets $S_1,S_2,...$ such that every relatively compact set $S$ is a subset of some $S_n$? Or to put it another way, the collection of relatively compact sets has a countable cofinal subcollection.

Is there some category of topological spaces which satisfies this property?  Maybe sigma-compact spaces?

My reason for asking this question, by the way, is that relatively compact sets form a [bornology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space) for $T_1$ spaces, and this property is one of the conditions for a bornology to be induced by a compatible metric, as I discuss [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3047070/71829).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think [hemicompactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicompact_space) comes close: this means that there are countably many compact $H_n\subseteq X$, $n \in \omega$, such that every compact subset of $X$ is a subset of some $H_n$. This condition is often considered when studying the compact-open topology on $X$.
This property implies $\sigma$-compactness but is stronger: $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\sigma$-compact but not hemicompact (see this [planetmath page](https://planetmath.org/hemicompactspace)), but for locally compact Hausdorff spaces the notions are equivalent.

It is clear that a hemicompact $X$ satisfies your condition, and a space satisfying your condition is hemicompact (using the closures of the base sets).

Comment: Thanks.  By the way, I just posted a follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3048232/71829