# What topological spaces satisfy yet another property involving relatively compact sets?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms, uniform-spaces

This is a follow-up to my questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3047093/71829) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3048148/71829).   A subset of a topological space is called relatively compact if its closure is compact.  Let's call a sequence $(U_n)$ of open sets a bounding sequence if the closure of $U_n$ is a subset of $U_{n+1}$ for all $n$ and every relatively compact set is a subset of some $U_n$.  And let's call a set $S$ saturated if for every bounding sequence $(U_n)$, $S$ is a subset of some $U_n$.  My question is, for what topological spaces is every saturated set relatively compact?

Is there some category of topological spaces which satisfies this property?  And is there an example of a completely regular space which doesn’t satisfy this property?

My reason for asking this question, by the way, is that relatively compact sets form a [bornology](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space) for $T_1$ spaces, and this property is the conditions for a bornology to be induced by a compatible uniformity, as I discuss [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3048140/71829).

Comment: Have you considered hemicompact spaces?  Bornological sets are simply subset ordered ideals, the order dual of filters.

Comment: Wait, why can't you just take each $U_n = X$ to be the whole topological space? As long as $X$ is not compact, not every saturated set will be relatively compact.

Comment: @mathworker21 There's nothing stopping you from considering the bounding sequence $(X,X,X,...)$.  But remember, a saturated set must be contained in some element of EVERY bounding sequence, not just one particular bounding sequence.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan oh wow, I can't believe I didn't read that. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the property is equivalent to that every closed saturated set is compact, so all compact spaces have the property. On the other hand, in a  trivial case when the space with the property has no bounding sequences then it is saturated, so compact.

For a space $X$ put $X_c=\{x\in X:\overline{\{x\}}$ is compact$ \}$ and 
$$X^+_c=\bigcap\{U\subset X: X_c\subset\operatorname{int} U\}=\{x\in X: \overline{\{x\}}\cap X_c\ne\varnothing\}.$$ It is easy to check that each relatively compact subset of $X$ is contained in $X_c$. If $X$ is $T_1$ then $X_c=X$. Recently Paolo Lipparini suggested us to consider spaces $X$ with the property (P) that $X=X_c$ (for other reasons). He observed that:

> This property (P) is much weaker than $T_1$,
>
> In general, the closure of a point might be non compact. E.g., $\Bbb N$ with the topology of left intervals, whose open sets are the intervals $[0, n)$, plus the whole of $\Bbb N$. Here the closure of $0$ is the noncompact $\Bbb N$. The example also shows that feeble compactness does not imply (P).

Clearly, each bounding sequence of a space $X$ is a cover of $X^+_c$. Conversely, if $(U_n)$ is a cover of a set $X_c$ by open sets such that $\overline{U_n}\subset U_{n+1}$  for all $n$ then $(U_n)$ is a bounding sequence. Indeed, let $B$ be a relatively compact subset of $X$. Then $\overline{B}\subset X_c$ is  compact. Thus $(U_n)$ is a non-decreasing open cover of a compact set $\overline{B}$, so there exists $n$ such that $B\subset \overline{B}\subset U_n$. Also remark that in this case a family $X^+_c\setminus \overline{U_n}$ is locally finite.

> As usual, a space $X$ is called feebly compact if every locally  finite family of open sets in X is finite. Feebly compact spaces are not assumed to satisfy any separation axiom, while pseudocompact spaces are necessarily Tychonoff. It is clear that feeble compactness and pseudocompactness coincide in
>   Tychonoff  spaces, so the former notion is a ’right’ extension of the latter one to non-Tychonoff
>   spaces.
>
> Let us recall that a subset $B$ of a space $X$ is said to be bounded in $X$ if every locally finite family of open sets in $X$ contains only finitely many elements that meet $B$. Hence boundedness is a relative version of feeble compactness. It is clear from the definition that a subset $B$ of a Tychonoff space $X$ is bounded in $X$ if and only if every continuous real-valued function defined on $X$ is bounded on $B$. [TS]

The above implies that each bounded subset of a space with property (P) is saturated. On the other hand, each saturated subset $B$ of $X$ is functionally bounded, that is if every continuous real-valued function defined on $X$ is bounded on $B$. Indeed, if $f:X\to\Bbb R$ is a continuous function unbounded on $B$, then $(f^{-1}(-n,n))$ is a bounding sequence witnessing that $B$ is not saturated. That is, a subset of a completely regular space is saturated iff it is functionally bounded. So a completely regular space has the property iff each its closed functionally bounded subset is compact. In particular, each pseudocompact space satisfying the property is compact. Recall that a subset $B$ of a normal space $X$ is functionally bounded iff $B$ is pseudocompact. Indeed, if $B$ is not pseudocompact then there exists a continuous real-valued unbounded function $f$ on $B$. Since $B$ is a closed subset of a normal space, by Tietze-Urysohn’s Theorem $f$ can be extended to a continuous real-valued (unbounded) function on the whole space, which violates functional boundedness of $B$.

Thus space $X$ has the property under the known condition assuring a pseudocompact space is compact.

- $X$ is paracompact. Indeed, by [Eng, Theorem 5.1.5] $X$ is normal. Let $B$ be any closed saturated subset of $X$. The set $B$ is paracompact as a closed subset of a  paracompact space. Since $B$ is feebly compact, it is compact.
- $X$ is a normal space with $G_\delta$-diagonal. Indeed, let $B$ be any closed saturated subset of $X$.
  Since $B$ is feebly compact and normal, by [Eng, Theorem 4.3.28] $B$ is countably compact. By Chaber’s Theorem [Gru, Theorem 2.14], $B$ is compact. See,  for instance [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457629/a-metric-space-is-compact-iff-it-is-pseudocompact/1457756#1457756) my answer for the formulations and proofs of the mentioned theorems.

*References*

[Eng] Ryszard Engelking, *General Topology*, 2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989.

[Gru] Gary Gruenhage *Generalized Metric Spaces*, in: K.Kunen, J.E.Vaughan (eds.) *Handbook of Set-theoretic Topology*, Elsevier Science Publishers B.V., 1984.

[TS] Iván Sánchez, Mikhail Tkachenko, *[Products of bounded subsets of paratopological groups](http://mat.izt.uam.mx/mat/documentos/produccion_academica/2015/53/ARTICULO%20ESPECIALIZADO%20DE%20INVESTIGACION-720.pdf)*, Topology Appl., **190** (2015), 42-58.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  By the way, do know of an example of a completely regular space that does not have the property?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes, of course. Recall that each pseudocompact space with the property is compact, so any pseudocompact non-compact space is an example. For instance, an ordinal $\omega_1$ endowed with the order topology or any proper space $X$ of $[0,1]^\kappa$, where $\kappa$ is an uncountable cardinal and $$X\supset \Sigma_\kappa I=\{(x_\alpha)_{\alpha<\kappa}\in [0,1]^\kappa: |\{\alpha: x_\alpha>0\}|\le\omega\}.$$

Comment: OK thanks for your help!